# Installation of Busybox on Pandaboard

Tags: android, embedded-linux, busybox, pandaboard

I am trying to install busy box on panda board which has ICS android kernel

steps are below that I used

1. Downloaded binary file which is supported to the panda board
2. Pushing it into system/busybox/ folder
3. Install the busybox command line tools on the target by executing the following commands on booted filesystem:

   ```
                    pc> ./adb shell
                    target$ cd /system/busybox
                    target$ ./busybox --install .
                    target$ ./sh  #here i am getting error like ./sh: precmd: not found
   ```
4. Save the original sh executable by renaming it, and then create a soft-link to busybox sh:

   ```
    target$ cd /system/bin
    target$ mv sh sh.android
    target$ ln -s /system/busybox/sh sh
   ```
5. After that  Export

   export PATH=$PATH:/system/busybox:/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin

I want to make Busybox shell as default shell so I can run script on Panda board, but I am getting error in 3rd step that I have mentioned there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `precmd` error seems to be due to the prompt. Try resetting the prompt, by doing:

```
$ unset PS1 PROMPT_COMMAND
```

Comment: but this will not solve my problem.as i want to make busybox shell as default shell .

Comment: I think for that, usually you would configure your embedded linux system at build time, using busybox for userspace. What you're doing seems unusual to me. I'd suggest reference book "Embedded Linux Primer" by Hallinan to see usual use of busybox.